# RSYNC only listing files when run from bash script

Tags: bash, scripting, rsync

I am trying to copy backup files of my companies mail server to our backup server via RSYNC.  I use this same script for backing up our web hosting server backup files with no issues.  When I type this out by hand from the command line it works perfectly, but when I run it from a bash script all I receive is the incremental file list and no files are copied.  Here is script I am running.  Please help!

```
#!/bin/bash

RSYNC=/usr/bin/rsync
SSH=/usr/bin/ssh
KEY=/root/cron/backup-rsync-key
RUSER=user
RHOST=mail.server.net
RPATH=/backup/path/
PATH=/backup/path/mailserver-folder

$RSYNC -ae "$SSH -i $KEY" --progress --log-file=rsync.log $RUSER@$RHOST:$RPATH $LPATH
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$LPATH` is not defined.  Your script has no destination to copy the files to.  You are missing an L where it says `PATH=/backup/path/mailserver-folder`.

Comment: Holy Cow!  Thanks for pointing that out.  Sometimes you look at something for so long something stupid like that slips past you.  I made the fix and it is working fine.  Thanks!